# how to show battery , wifi in jwm status bar

Tags: linux, window-manager

am switching to JWM window manager , but the problem is that it does not have a battery percentage or network connection , also i cannot increase screen brightness ? is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

`ls /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/*` files provide access to information about battery state. See `energy_full` and `energy_now` files to calculate remaining percentage, `status` to see whether the battery is charging/discharging, etc.

You may use the `acpi` utility to display ACPI battery information for you, including time remaining to charge the battery, etc. Look the package up for your distro.